# Python modifying csv column by increments

Tags: python, csv, time

First off, I apologize for the terrible title; I didn't know how to summarize my problem. Okay, so here's a the first few lines of my .csv file. The first column is the timestamp. The program I'm getting this data from samples 24 times per second, so there are 24 rows that start with 15:40:15, 24 that start with 15:40:16, and so on. Instead of 24 rows with the same timestamp, I want the timestamp to increase increments of 1/24 seconds, or .042 seconds. So 15:40:15.042, 15:40:15.084, etc.

Another problem is that there aren't 24 rows for the first second, because we start in the middle of the second. For example, there are only 13 15:40:14 rows. For those it would preferably count backwards from 15:40:15.000 and subtract .042 seconds for every row.

How can I do this in Python? Thanks in advance!

```
CPUtime,Displacement Into Surface,Load On Sample,Time On Sample,Raw Load,Raw Displacement
15:40:14,-990.210561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.999137,-989.210000
15:40:14,-989.810561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.999105,-988.810000
15:40:14,-989.410561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.999073,-988.410000
15:40:14,-989.010561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.999041,-988.010000
15:40:14,-988.590561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.999007,-987.590000
15:40:14,-988.170561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.998974,-987.170000
15:40:14,-987.770561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.998942,-986.770000
15:40:14,-987.310561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.998905,-986.310000
15:40:14,-986.870561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.998870,-985.870000
15:40:14,-986.430561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.998834,-985.430000
15:40:14,-985.990561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.998799,-984.990000
15:40:14,-985.570561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.998766,-984.570000
15:40:14,-985.170561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.998734,-984.170000
15:40:15,-984.730561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.998698,-983.730000
15:40:15,-984.310561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.998665,-983.310000
15:40:15,-983.890561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.998631,-982.890000
15:40:15,-983.490561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.998599,-982.490000
15:40:15,-983.090561,-0.000025,1.7977E+308,-115.998567,-982.090000
```

Comment: I have no idea how to start :( I'm a newbie. I thought to look through the csv module documentation but I'm pretty lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add to [@robert king's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11787324/4279) that you could use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group rows with the same timestamp:

```
import csv
import shutil
from itertools import groupby

n = 24
time_increment = 1./n
fractions = [("%.3f" % (i*time_increment,)).lstrip('0') for i in xrange(n)]

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f, open('output.csv', 'wb') as fout:
     writer = csv.writer(fout)
     # assume the file is sorted by timestamp
     for timestamp, group in groupby(csv.reader(f), key=lambda row: row[0]):
         sametime = list(group) # all rows that have the same timestamp
         assert n >= len(sametime)
         for i, row in enumerate(sametime, start=n-len(sametime)):
             row[0] += fractions[i] # append fractions of a second
         writer.writerows(sametime)

shutil.move('output.csv', 'input.csv') # update input file
```

- 'b' file mode is mandatory for csv in Python 2 otherwise entries that may span several physical lines won't work
- if there are less than `n` entries with the same timestamp then the code assumes that they are consecutive values from the end of a second

Comment: Thanks! There's a lot I can learn from this! One thing, though - what's the assert n>= len(sametime) for? It got me an error message so I deleted it.

Comment: @IntrnetHteMchne: `assert n >= len(sametime)` makes sure that there are less than 25 consecutive rows with the same timestamp. If it doesn't work with the assert statement then your input is invalid and you should investigate the rows.

Comment: Nice answer showing good standard practice. The groupby + writerows makes for a good combo

Comment: @ J.F. Sebastian ah, gotcha. I actually miscounted, and there are 25 rows with the same timestamp! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

open the csv file and create a csv reader as per http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Also create a csv writer as per http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Now loop through each row of the file. On each row, modify the timestamp and then write it to your new csv file.

If you want the new csv file to replace the old csv file, at the end use shutil http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html to replace it.

I recommend inside your loop you have a variable called "current_timestamp" and a variable called "current_increment". If the timestamp in the row is equal to the current_timestamp, simply add the increment, otherwise change them both appropriately.